Spider identification: Nesticodes rufipes or Loxosceles gaucho? (South of Brazil)
I need help identifying a spider species frequently encountered in my apartment in Porto Alegre, southern Brazil.

Habitat: Found indoors on ceiling/wall corners, door frames, and behind paintings.
Web pattern: No discernible regular web pattern observed.
Size: Body length approximately 5mm, excluding legs.
Geographic location: Porto Alegre, Rio Grande do Sul, Brazil.
Behaviour and other notes: I've found them on any season, any time of day, and not hidden at all (ceiling/wall corners). They are usually standing still, and when prodded with a stick either curl up into a ball or very quickly draw a string of web and descend. I've seen much smaller ones (spiderlings?) whose body length is 1mm or less.

I think might be either of these:

Nesticodes rufipes
Loxosceles gaucho

I took some photos to the best of my ability/equipment, all of them are the same specimen but under different lighting and angles:






I've contacted Instituto Butantan (main producer of antivenoms and antitoxins in Brazil), inquired about this specimen and forwarded these photos.
They have confirmed it is Nesticodes rufipes.
